# 'ContentMode' is not a member type of 'UIView'

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have the following piece of code which works well for a legacy IOS app, but now no longer works in xcode 9:

The error I'm getting is:

```
'ContentMode' is not a member type of 'UIView'
```

Here is the code:

```
import Foundation

struct ImageViewLayout {
    static func frameForImageWithSize(_ image: CGSize, previousFrame: CGRect, inContainerWithSize container: CGSize, usingContentMode contentMode: UIView.ContentMode) -> CGRect {
        let size = sizeForImage(image, previousSize: previousFrame.size, container: container, contentMode: contentMode)
        let position = positionForImage(size, previousPosition: previousFrame.origin, container: container, contentMode: contentMode)

        return CGRect(origin: position, size: size)
    }
```

Comment: Adding import UIKit hasn't fixed the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The enum type name `UIView.ContentMode` is new in Swift 4.2, introduced in Xcode 10. Before that (e.g. Xcode 9, as you say) it was `UIViewContentMode`.